# Is it legal to use software that is no longer available for purchase?

Tags: copyright, software

The company where I work bought a Bootstrap template that suits my requirements at another company. This template is no longer available for purchase. Can the other company use the template?

Comment: A template isn't really software is it?

Comment: If it was software I think it would fall under abandoware aka grey area technically illegal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most software is sold as a license.  If so *check the terms of the license*: They might provide for transfer, extension, or some other mechanism that would allow an entity other than the original licensee to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it legally if you have permission of the copyright holder. Which may be hard to get.